# The difference between ''de'' and ''à des''

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

''Le mixage, le metissage, **l'emprunt à des cultures** differentes sont des caracteristiques essentielles de cette population.''

''Le mixage, le metissage, **l'emprunt de cultures** differentes sont des caracteristiques essentielles de cette population.''

What's the difference? In my manual I have the first form, ''à des'', and I can't understand why not the second one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning is different.

*l'emprunt à des cultures* = borrowing from cultures (borrowing something from cultures)

*l'emprunt de cultures* = borrowing of cultures (two possible meanings - either borrowing the cultures themselves, or the cultures doing the borrowing)

Answer (score 1):

Ms LKL explains it very well. Just my two cents:

1. "...l'emprunt à des cultures differentes sont des caracteristiques essentielles de cette population" => *ce qui est emprunté*; i.e. **the adaptations of** different cultures are referred to as the 'caracteristiques essentielles'.
2. "...l'emprunt de cultures differentes sont des caracteristiques essentielles de cette population" => *ce qui les cultures ont empruntés,  d'origine ailleurs*; i.e. **the borrowings made by** the different cultures are referred to as the 'caracteristiques essentielles'.